# Handshake problem when no. of handshakes are given

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've tried to do the following problem:
At the end of a meeting, all participants shake hands with each other. $28$ handshakes were exchanged. How many people attended the meeting?

What I tried:
If there are $n$ people, the first one does $n-1$ handshakes. The second one $n-2$. The third $n-3$ and so on until $1$ handshake. 
So an arithmetic series is there with $n-1$ members, the sum of which is equal to $28$. 
Using
 SUM$=\frac{n-1}{2} \cdot (\text{1st term} + \text{last term}) = 28$
1st term is $n-1$
Last term is $1$

We get $n(n-1)=56$
A quadratic equation is obtained 
$n^2 -n -56 = 0$

Edit: $n=8$
I'm sorry I was very sleepy. I couldn't do simple factoring.

Comment: You have already had the answer.

Comment: see http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/factoring.html for help on factoring.

Comment: Ohh. Im so sleepy. I couldn't do factoring...

Comment: Since $0=n^2-n-56=(n-8)(n+7)$ you could also have $-7$ people - unless there is a reason why this solution does not make sense ...

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the *handshaking-lemma* (or by combinatorial argument), the number of handshakes that take place will be $\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n^2-n}{2}$.

If we know the total number of handshakes is 28, this gives us the following equation:

$$28 = \frac{n^2-n}{2}$$

By moving everything to one side of the equation, we have then:

$$0 = n^2-n-56$$

From which we can use the quadratic equation to solve for $n$.

> The quadratic equation:  For an equation of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$, the solutions for $x$ are given as:
>
> $$x = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

$$n = \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4\cdot 56}}{2} = \frac{1+\sqrt{225}}{2} = \frac{1+15}{2} = 8$$

Comment: I was/ am sleepy. I couldnt do simple factoring. Silly me! ;)